# Why is `if x is None: pass` faster than `x is None` alone?

Tags: python, performance, cpython, micro-optimization, python-internals

Timing results in Python 3.12 (and similar with 3.11 and 3.13 on different machines):

```
When x = None:
13.8 ns  x is None
10.1 ns  if x is None: pass

When x = True:
13.9 ns  x is None
11.1 ns  if x is None: pass
```

How can doing **more** take **less** time?

Why is `if x is None: pass` faster, when it does the same `x is None` check and then additionally checks the truth value of the result (and does or skips the `pass`)?

Times on other versions/machines:

- Python 3.11: (12.4, 9.3) and (12.0, 8.8)
- Python 3.13: (12.7, 9.9) and (12.7, 9.6)

Benchmark script ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZAxTgMxEEVF657-d15HS5QFCmRpr4AokCgQRQRjxcXalj1BG632JDRp4FCcBnudREw145n39f2_fsKBd94dj997NjcPv1fXJvoBbAeyDDsEHxmRAm1ZnKZ0SEIYHzHCOjx6Ry2e4560QK4QrePGyJcdOUwjesxaqmVVmHf_QQV7lZlOCy1bSGtwmTXCNiX5hhVuq2YpzkqDdU310hSdFkZOYz9ngfrad5uNUhfkbGXiVUd3-n7dmRkuId8XXP3zq4SojXxa8tD5Jv9z_UkxWe9UTecU0jmsPw)):

```py
from timeit import repeat
import sys

for x in None, True:
    print(f'When {x = }:')
    for code in ['x is None', 'if x is None: pass'] * 2:
        t = min(repeat(code, f'{x=}', repeat=100))
        print(f'{t*1e3:4.1f} ns ', code)
    print()

print('Python:', sys.version)
```

Comment: Interesting finding. If you disassemble the bytecode ,it's even less clear that there should be a difference in favor of the `if` version.

Comment: @kindall What Python version did you use?

Comment: @rioV8 Sorry our edits collided. Though since I have Python expressions in there, I do like the Python coloring there. I also like the highlighted times, I only wish the version line was gray. Maybe I'll just remove it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the disassembled code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('if x is None: pass')
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 POP_JUMP_IF_NOT_NONE     1 (to 8)
              6 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)
        >>    8 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)
>>> dis.dis('x is None')
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `if` case has a special `POP_JUMP_IF_NOT_NONE` operation, which is faster than a `LOAD_CONST` plus `IS_OP`. You can read the detailed discussion about it here: https://github.com/faster-cpython/ideas/discussions/154.

Answer (score 1):

To augment what @deceze showed, here's what happens when we **don't** use `None` but a **variable** `none` set to `None`. Then Python doesn't compile that to the special `POP_JUMP_IF_NOT_NONE` but as expected to the same `LOAD_NAME`+`LOAD_NAME`+`IS_OP` as for `x is none`, plus a `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` that indeed does a truth check of the `IS_OP` result and then jumps or not. And as expected, that *does* take longer ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZAxbgIxFESV1qeYzmu0IDZJgYz2CogiUoooBUps4WK_LdugRas9SRqa5FCcBnsNKL_yl-eN5s_PnzvFvaXz-fcQ9Xx1eYL2tkM0nTIRpnPWR3jl1C6y2xZOgTFtPXoYwsaSqvHmD0oypHHeUKw0f98rwtCjxSi5mL4y82W_VcY-eKIDKNG8Bjcaj13C7ULgn5jhuXjmicmpM1SVLFX2qaH50LfjesLaTfEqgrZZLoV40PdUQ5w16kW-Lho9ggKSPjuJf9EFY-XBt1M1MmnSyYuj8sFYEqWoW1_33q4)):

```
When x = None:
13.6 ns  x is none
15.0 ns  if x is none: pass

When x = True:
13.6 ns  x is none
14.5 ns  if x is none: pass
```

Bytecode for `x is none`:

```
  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (none)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Bytecode for `if x is none: pass`:

```
  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (none)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        1 (to 12)
             10 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)
        >>   12 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)
```